# Discord.js TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'messages')

Tags: javascript, discord.js, request-promise

I'm coding a discord bot and I've coded a function that fetches  messages from a channel on discord, but the bot can't read messages. I couldn't solve the problem, can anyone help me?

**Error Stack:**

```
An error occurred while trying to fetch the channels:  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'messages')
    at file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/gb-ac-bot/src/utils.js:7:88
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.allMessagesFromChannelList (file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/gb-ac-bot/src/utils.js:7:53)
    at Object.updateServerInfo (file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/gb-ac-bot/src/scheduler.js:6:34)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/gb-ac-bot/src/index.js:53:21)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
```

**My utils.js File:**

```
const allMessagesFromChannelList = async (client) => {
const channels = global.channels.map(id => client.channels.cache.get(id))

try {
    const messages = await Promise.all(channels.map(async channel => await channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 50 })))
    return messages.map(collection => collection.map(value => value))
        .flat()
        .filter(msg => msg.author.id === global.botId)
} catch (error) {
    console.error('An error occurred while trying to fetch the channels: ', error)
    return []
}
```

}

The line of code that throws that error (line 7):

```js
const messages = await Promise.all(channels.map(async channel => await channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 50 })))
```

Comment: Is it just me or this line `channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 50 })` should be `channels.messages.fetch({ limit: 50 })`?

Comment: @新Acesyyy the context from the rest of that line shows that channel is correct. `...await Promise.all(channels.map(>>async channel<< => await channel.messages.fetch...` emphasis added by me